# Quantifying the sustained(ness) or intermittent(ness) of a series 0s and 1s

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I am working with movement data that includes people's upright time and their activity (stepping or standing) during that upright time. I aim to classify events as either 'sustained' or 'intermittent' based on this information.

For instance, consider a 20-minute upright event with consecutive $0$s and $1$s representing standing and stepping, respectively, each with their associated durations (summing to 20 minutes). This could be a single 20-minute standing event ($0$) or a combination of alternating standing and stepping events ($0,1,0,1,0,1,0$), each with their respective durations.

I can calculate the proportion of standing duration to stepping duration within this 20-minute upright event. However, I would like to determine how the stepping events are accumulated. For example, is it a 10-minute standing event followed by a 10-minute stepping event (which would be considered sustained)? Or is it a sequence of alternating 1-minute standing and stepping events (which would be considered intermittent)?

I am seeking an approach to quantify the "intermittentness" or "sustainedness" of these upright events. Any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed with this problem would be appreciated.